# Exponent vs. Proponent

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

"Exponent" and "proponent" seem to have (at least) overlapping definitions in the sense of "one who advocates". What distinguishes them?

Comment: I've never personally heard the term *exponent* used as anything but the degree of a power in mathematics.

Comment: @JoeZ: Nor had I, except perhaps rarely, until [this](http://www.neatorama.com/2014/11/04/Centrifuging-Mental-Patients/) (approx. 3rd paragraph - about the middle of the first block quote).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED defines an ***exponent*** as: *One who sets forth in words, expounds, or interprets; in recent use occas. one who ‘interprets’ music, an executant. Also, that which serves to explain or interpret.*

A ***proponent*** on the other hand is:

*A person who puts forward or advocates a theory, proposal, or course of action; a propounder, a proposer. In later use also more generally: a person who is in favour of a proposal, a supporter.*

The principal difference, therefore, seems to me to be that whilst an *exponent* 'sets forth and interprets', a *proponent* advocates. A proponent provides more opinionated support for a proposition than an *exponent* who merely explains. That is how I see the difference.

Comment: If we're going to use OED, note also defn 3 *He who or that which sets forth as a representative or type, as a symbol or index*, for which a cited usage is *Theobald ... as a plodding antiquarian, was an excellent exponent of dullness.* We can safely assume Theobald never actively attempted to persuade people to espouse dullness - the point is an *exponent* can just be passively serving as a *good example*, but a *proponent* always actively promotes his cause.

Comment: A musician described as a leading *exponent of Wagner's music* might be someone who plays Wagner very well even if they acknowledge he was evil and antisemitic, while a *proponent of Wagner's music* might not play the music but probably would try and excuse the antisemitism while advocating for his greatness.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is much difference in terms of each word's connotation.  However, proponent is more commonly used.

Exponent is rooted in the infinitive *expose*, while proponent is rooted in *propose*.  If I were to dig into the nuances of the two words, I would use exponent in situations where the subject is choosing to emphasize something that most people would agree is factually correct, and I would use proponent when the subject is proposing something that isn't necessarily true from an objective standpoint, or that is more subjective by nature.

Comment: To back up akorff's definition we can actually get 1 step closer than "expose" and "propose". A proponent is "one who propounds" {propound = put forward for consideration}. An exponent is "one who expounds" {expound = present and explain a theory or idea systematically and in detail.}  

Interestingly the root is the same, but *pose words have evolved representing literal actions and *pound words representing figurative actions. So an exposer exposes a fact, but exponent expounds a theory. We compose a poem, but we make compound words.

Answer (score 0):

I remember the differences by attaching them to the underlying words:

A person might ex-pose (an idea) - ex-ponent
A person might pro-pose (an idea) - pro-ponent